# fragment.isVisible() always returns false

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to set up an overlay fragment that would appear when the button is touched and disappear when the button is clicked again. I'm not using the support library fragment, but the regular kind. So when you click on the button to attach the fragment, it does so, here's the code:

```
boolean hasNativeFrag = false;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.native_chat) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        NativeFragment nativeFragment = new NativeFragment();

        //Add/remove fragment
        if (!hasNativeFrag) {
            getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, nativeFragment);

            hasNativeFrag = true;
        }

        if(nativeFragment.isVisible()){
            fragmentTransaction.hide(nativeFragment);
        }
        else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(nativeFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But when I click on the button again, I expect the if condition to run, since it's visible now, and it should hide it. Nevertheless nativeFragment.isVisible() always returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a bunch

Update 1:
Couldn't get it to work with any of the methods proposed by the answers, but a simple boolean at least switches between them like so:

```
boolean hasNativeFrag = false;
boolean isNativeFragShown = false;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.native_chat) {
        Log.v("NativeChat", "NativeChat");

        //Instantiate fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        NativeFragment nativeFragment = new NativeFragment();


        //Show/Hide

        if (isNativeFragShown) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(nativeFragment);
            Log.d("Hidden", "Hidden");
            isNativeFragShown = false;

        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(nativeFragment);
            Log.d("Shown", "Shown");
            isNativeFragShown = true;
        }

        //Add/remove fragment
        if (!hasNativeFrag) {
            getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, nativeFragment);
            isNativeFragShown = true;
            hasNativeFrag = true;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The log says that it is toggling between the functions, which is good, but the fragment is still visible, even after using .hide

Am I referencing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new fragment everytime your native_chat  button is pressed and this new fragment will never be visible until it is added/shown. Try adding a field to hold onto a reference of this fragment and determine visibility of one that was already created. Also, I think you want an if/else for the action_settings button.

```
NativeFragment nativeFragment = null;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.native_chat) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (nativeFragment == null) {
            // fragment doesn't exist, lets create and add one
            nativeFragment = new NativeFragment();
            getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, nativeFragment);
        }

        if(nativeFragment.isVisible()){
            fragmentTransaction.hide(nativeFragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(nativeFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: With a couple breakpoints I can see that the check for hasNativeFrag works, and that the .add block is run only once, on first run. Subsequent clicks jump straight to the isVisible check, which is always true, even before the first run has reached the .commit. I must be referencing the wrong thing in the visibility check. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I thought you said _nativeFragment.isVisible() always returns false_

Comment: You're right, I neglected to say I was trying the method getUserVisibleHint() suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Ok,  that makes sense.  Given the code in your question you really are creating a new NativeFragment on each button press which will never be visible until it is added and shown.  As for the `hasNativeFrag` boolean, it is a good start, but felt the  wasn't enough when we can use a field type of NativeFragment for determination in its place.

Answer (score 5):

You can use to following method `getUserVisibleHint()` to determine if your fragment is visible or not to the user

Comment: If the fragment is a nested fragment then you can also check 'getParentFragment().getUserVisibleHint()'.